# In MySQL, how to split a deliminated string with more than one value per delimination

Tags: mysql, split

Suppose I have this string being passed to my stored procedure:
    '1,10;2,11;3,12'
I need to split this out so that I can insert into a table like this:

```
   ID   VALUE
   1      10
   2      11
   3      12
```

What MySQL code can I use to both split the string and insert into the table as shown?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a query such as this to break up the string:

```
select substring_index(substring_index(substring_index('1,10;2,11;3,12', ';', n.n), ';', -1), ',', 1) as id,
       substring_index(substring_index(substring_index('1,10;2,11;3,12', ';', n.n), ';', -1), ',', 1) as value
from (select 1 as n union all select 2 union all select 3) n;
```

You can put `insert into t(id, value)` before this for an `insert`.